# Get values of all checked radio buttons using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Using JQuery I am trying to perform validation and also get the values of all the dynamically generated Radio buttons in the page.

I have 10 questions on my page and each question has a Radio button group(YES/NO).

when click in the radio button i want to send it's value to database for the question, this is my code

```
<p>Question 1</p>
<input id="1_1" type="radio" name="1" value="Yes" />
<input id="1_2" type="radio" name="1" value="NO" />
```

i searched in google and found this code

```
$('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val()
```

But I don't know what is the right way to use it ?

Answer (score 4):

As per your HTML structure try this :-

```
var arr = []; // take an array to store values
$('input[type="radio"][name="1"]:checked').each(function(){
   arr.push($(this).val());  //push values in array
});
```

Comment: OK when i wanna send it to direct to database is there any way ?

Comment: @AhmedAdm..it depends which server side technology you are using...but simple way is to make a ajax request and save values to database.

Comment: i have some knowldeg in jquery but in this case i do not know how to get value for all radio buttons one by one when clicked

i used php

Comment: @AhmedAdm..the code written in this answer will work for you..just use this code just before submitting your form and save it in database...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the values of all `<radio>` you can do

```
var ans = $('[name=1]:checked').map(funciton(){
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```